# How to find missing number between range of incremented numbers?

Tags: c#, math

Good day foreveryone,

Let's assume I have range of numbers, say from 0 to 10. And the client removed one item from them. I need to know which mathematical formula should I know to find out the missing number. (Using C#). I guess there is a relation between sum and count for this group of numbers.

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(start, count).Where(num => !myRangeOfNumbers.Contains(num))`

Comment: I'm not sure the title matches the description of this question..

Comment: @BrootsWaymb yes you right, I changed it

Comment: If you know what the complete range is, and you have the range with _only one missing number_,  you only need to subtract the [sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netcore-3.1) of the range with the missing number from the sum of the complete range.

Answer (score 2):

I think your teacher expects you to know the Little Gauss formula.

Don’t want to spoil all your homework, so just sum the numbers you have left and check what you are missing since you know the total from this formula.

History:
http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/qq.02.06/jo1.html

Comment: PS: The answer you get doing it this way runs in O(n).   Brute force like suggested in the comments above is O(n^2).  I am guessing that’s the “clever” part of why this question asks specifically about removing one number from a consecutive sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
1,2,3,5,6
```

Output
Missing Number : 4

Now to calculate missing number

Solution:
total numbers=5
sum of 6 numbers from 1 to 6 =

```
6*(6+1)/2;   
//Count(input)*(count(input)+1)/2
=21;
```

sum of the Numbers in the sequence =17.

```
//sum(input) 
=17;
```

missing Number=sum of 6 numbers-sum of the Numbers in the sequence

```
= 21-17 = 4
```